# Return count of records in each row SQL

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have one table like this.

```
 SQL> SELECT * FROM FRUIT;

 F_NAME
 ----------
 APPLE
 PPPALEP
 APLEE
 PPAALLEEPP
 ornPpfpP    
 PPdhppPP
```

Above one is my source table and I want to below output.If i am giving 'P' in multiform like including capital and small both.
I want to count only 'P' from each row.

```
OUTPUT
------
F_NAME      COUNT
------      -----
APPLE         2
PPPALEP       4
APLEE         1
PPAALLEEPP    4
ornPpfpP      4
PPdhppPP      6
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of occurrences by replacing `P` with blanks and subtracting the length of the replaced string from the original string.

```
select f_name,length(f_name)-length(replace(f_name,'P','')) cnt
from fruit
```

Edit: Per OP's comment, to count both `P` and `p`, use `upper` or `lower` when replacing the character with an empty string.

```
select f_name,length(f_name)-length(replace(upper(f_name),'P','')) cnt
from fruit
```

Comment: This query is working fine for only count capital 'P' .If i am giving 'P' in multiform like including capital and small both. I want to count both 'P'(like capital and small) from each row.Then what is the logic.

Comment: Thanks in advance @vkp

Comment: Now i got my answer.Thanks @vkp

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has the very convenient `regexp_count()`.  So:

```
select f_name, regexp_count(f_name, 'P') as cnt
from fruit;
```

Comment: i didn't know about this function. thanks. i see it was introduced in oracle 11g.

Comment: I have tried a lot using regexp_count,but it is not working in oracle 10g.